# Populate HTML radio button based on user choice submitted in Database

Tags: php, html

One quick question. 
I am creating a web page using PHP, HTML and my requirement is to select a radio button by depending on choice(say 'Yes' or "No', yes selected by default). User selects 'No' and submits a form. I enter the choice in a database. When the site is re-visited, How do i make the selection based on the value retrieved from the database? I am able to get the values selected using PHP to connect to datatbase.

Thanks for the help. Let me know if more info is required,
Below is the current code snippet.

```
<input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="Areyou3" name="Areyou3" value="1" />
 <label for="input_40_0"> Yes </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
  <span class="form-radio-item" style="clear:left;">
   <input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="Areyou3" name="Areyou3" value="0" />
   <label for="input_40_1"> No </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
```

Comment: Fix your labels and ids. The for attribute maps onto the id attribute of the element the label is for, and ids must be unique (the two radio buttons must have different ids).

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
<input type="radio" name="Areyou3" value="yes"<?PHP ('yes' == $valueInDatabase)? ' checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
<input type="radio" name="Areyou3" value="no"<?PHP ('no' == $valueInDatabase)? ' checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
<?php 
if($valFromDB=='Yes')
$checked = 'checked';
else
$checked = '';
?>
<input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="Areyou3" name="Areyou3" value="1"  <?php echo $checked?>/>
<label for="input_40_0"> Yes </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
<span class="form-radio-item" style="clear:left;">
<input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="Areyou3" name="Areyou3" value="0" <?php echo $checked?>/>
<label for="input_40_1"> No </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
```